# Automate making imagery index layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, imagery

I am wanting to come up with a way to speed up my Imagery Index layer.
To give you an overview I have about 500 imagery files. They cover extents all over Australia.
I am wanting to create a shapefile with the outlines of the imagery extents and populate it with the date the imagery was taken and region its in. I am then wanting to turn this into a layer so I can use it to see what areas our imagery covers and it makes it easy to find which image I am after.

Currently I am just dragging in each image, drawing a box around it and then populating it with year and area.

I was told there is was way I can point my Python script to a folder and it will
draw the imagery extents as in that folder and add source location to the metadata.

Any ideas?

Below shows shapefile extent over imagery.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If all the images are the same type, you want to look into creating a [Mosaic dataset](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/what-is-a-mosaic-dataset.htm)

Comment: Yes but that does not put in the source location just the name of the image in the metadata?

Comment: You can use Export Raster Catalog Paths (Data Management) and join the output to the footprints 

help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000091000000